# How do I create a simple joomla plugin?

Tags: plugins, joomla

I'm having a real problem unstanding somthing thats probably very easy about creating and using joomla plugins.

Here is what I've done so far.

I've created a sample joomla plugin using the following two files inside of a folder and named them all the same.

I listed their contents below.

The plugin installs correctly through the admin panel

Then I enable it through plugin manager

ok. all set to go.

How do I use the plugin on an article once I've enabled the plugin?

ZIP FOLDER: MakePlugIn
FOLDER: MakePlugIn

MakePlugIn.php  -

```
<?php 
// No direct access allowed to this file
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// Import Joomla! Plugin library file
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

//The Content plugin MakePlugIn
class plgContentMakePlugIn extends JPlugin
{
    function plgContentMakePlugIn (&$subject)
    {
        parent::__construct ($subject);
    }
    function onPrepareContent (&$article, &$params, $page=0)
    {
        print "I am a happy plugin";
    }
}
?>
```

MakePlugIn.xml  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install version="1.5" type="plugin" group="content">
    <name>Make-Plug-In</name>
    <author>Make-Plug-In</author>
    <creationDate>03/15/2011</creationDate>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2011 Holder. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License</license>
    <authorEmail>authoremail@website.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.authorwebsite.com</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <description>Make-Plug-In test</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="MakePlugIn">MakePlugIn.php</filename>
    </files>
</install>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be `echo`ing or `print`ing information in the plug-in.

The method is receiving article reference as a parameter, modify it and you are good. You can use `var_dump` to quickly identify proper object type and properties.

Here is [Joomla tutorial on creating Content Plug-in](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin).

---

Updated on 3/17/2011

This is in response to first comment.
In order to modify the article modify the value of referenced object `&$article`.
See example below:

```
function onPrepareContent( &$article, &$params, $limitstart )
{
    //   Include you file with ajax code
    JHTML::_('script', 'ajax-file.js', 'media/path/to/js/dir/');

    //   Create ajax div
    $ajaxDiv = '<div id="ajax-div"></div>';

    // Modify article text by adding the div for ajax at the top
    $article->text = $ajaxDiv . PHP_EOL . $article->text;

    return true;
}
```

[Adding external JS to the head of the document](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript).

Comment: I'm working through the docs. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way though. If I wanted to add <div id='elementid'></div> above every article text of a certain category, then load the div using ajax, would I be more likely to be building a plugin or module or .... I'm already using ajax in the site but I had to edit the template through template manager to include the lib.. Which I would like to avoid in the future by making an easy uploadable package containing everything i need. I'm starting small with it so... any thoughts for direction are welcome.

Comment: I updated the answer, added example of how to use the article object